# mysqlimport --- appending to table with indexes

Tags: mysql, csv, indexing, import-from-csv, mysqlimport

Kindly suggest the correct way to use mysqlimport for appending to a table, that contains indexes, by reading from a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add indexes in .csv data file. I suggest a sql dump or a csv followed by creating indexes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a table for receiving the current csv file.
2. Do the import into that table.
3. (Optional) Cleanup the data.
4. Copy it into the `real` table:

something like

```
INSERT INTO `real`
    SELECT ... FROM csv;
```

In that step may (or may not) need to specify the columns, the order of the columns, `NULL` to avoid messing up an `AUTO_INCREMENT` in `real` but not in csv.